# How to find the not null values in php and display in if condition

Tags: php, php-5.6

Here i have one array in that array i want to find **not null** values and display in frond end ,suppose in this array all key values in **null** means i want to display all values are null,suppose any one of the key is not null means i want to display what is that value

```
<?php
$array = array('a' => '','b' => 'Kani' , 'c' => '', 'd' => 'Raja');

 if (in_array(null, $array)) {

     echo "There are null values.";
 }else{
  echo "Not Null";
 }
?>
```

> Here key a and d is not null so i want take this key value like Kani
>   and Raja

Comment: Your example array doesn't contain any `null` values but some empty strings.

Comment: can you please update your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want not empty not null array try like this

```
  <?php 
     print_r(array_filter(array('a' => '','b' => 'Kani' , 'c' => '', 'd' => 'Raja')));
  ?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/737817

Answer (score 0):

hey there you can use this :

```
$notNulvals = array();
$index =0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value) { 
        array_push($notNulvals, $value);
        $index=1;
    }
}

if ($index!=0) {
    echo "all values are null";
} else {
    echo $notNulvals; //you can display it the way you want 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've forgotten to specify the third parameter to in_array.

```
 if (in_array(null, $array, true)) {
  echo "There are null values.";
 }else{
  echo "Not Null";
 }
```

This way it will tell if there is an actual null value in the array.